# Extracting tokens from a reference file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I am writing a script, there is a section where the script needs to fetch the server name and port detail from a reference file.

I have used the below logic to fetch the details, however I am looking for some better option. Please advise.

```
HOST=$(grep SERVER_NAME $HOME/env.ref | awk -F '=' '{print $2}')
PORT=$(grep SERVER_PORT $HOME/env.ref | awk -F '=' '{print $2}')

if [ "${HOST}" -a "{PORT}" ]
then
echo "Details extracted"
else
echo "Details not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to pipe grep into awk.  try this:

   ```
   HOST="$(awk -F= '/SERVER_NAME/ {print $2}' $HOME/env.ref)"
   PORT="$(awk -F= '/SERVER_PORT/ {print $2}' $HOME/env.ref)"
   ```
2. if/then/else is more readable if you a) don't waste a line on `then` and b) indent the clauses.   Also, you don't need to use `{...}` around variables unless there's a possibility of ambiguity.  e.g. `$HOSTPORT` is a single variable called $HOSTPORT, while `${HOST}${PORT}` is two variables concatenated without anything between them.  Finally, you forgot the `$` on `$PORT`.

   ```
   if [ "$HOST" -a "$PORT" ] ; then 
     echo "Details extracted"
   else
     echo "Details not found"
   fi
   ```

   And if all you're going to do is just echo found or not found, it can be done on one line:

   ```
   [ "$HOST" -a "$PORT" ] && echo "Details extracted" || echo "Details not found"
   ```

There isn't much else in your script that could be improved much.  There's just not enough there.  Depending on exactly what the rest of your script is doing, it may be better to write the whole thing in awk or perl or python or something...but it's impossible to know without a description or large script 
sample.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format of this file is `name=value` lines, you could do this in plain shell (`bash` or `zsh`):

```
while read -r line; do 
    case "$line" in 
        SERVER_NAME=*|SERVER_PORT=*) declare "$line";; 
    esac
done < env.ref
echo "$SERVER_NAME"
echo "$SERVER_PORT"
```

That reads the file, and when the specified lines are found, use [the `declare` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare) to create the variables in this current shell (though when called inside a function, note that it would restrict the scope of that variable to that function (unless you use `declare -g`)).

Comment: Note that in `bash`, contrary to most other shells `declare -g` (typeset being more portable) is not to prevent the variable being declared _local_, but to change the type or value of the variable in the top-most scope, so `declare -g` may not do what you want if the variable was already declared local in an outer scope. `bash -c 'a=1; f() { declare a=2; g; }; g() { declare -g a=3; echo "$a"; }; f'` outputs 2, not 3 and the wrong variable is being modified.